# Updated way to write this NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui

I am writing a program and noticed that the NavigationLink I used is deprecated. I wondering how I would do an updated version of this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text("You are logged in @(username)"), isActive: $showingLoginScreen) {
    EmptyView()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `NavigationLink` wasn't deprecated until now, just some `init` functions were deprecated. According to the documentation, they recommend using it inside a `NavigationStack` or `NavigationSplitView`. You can see it on the deprecated message.

> @available(iOS, introduced: 13.0, deprecated: 16.0, message: "use NavigationLink(value:label:) inside a NavigationStack or NavigationSplitView")

```swift
@State private var showingLoginScreen = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        Button {
            showingLoginScreen = true
        } label: {
            Text("You are logged in @(username)")
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showingLoginScreen) {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I go about adding the $showingLoginScreen for the isActive part, I get everything else @son

Comment: using `.navigationDestination(isPresented)` instead @SmartGamer.